# AR passing same object through different cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've set up a network lobby allowing both users to join the same room (multiplayer). I am using Vuforia with the networking Identity to allow objects to appear from a card. However, once both users enter the same room only one can view the object from the card. Both users are not able to see each other's object which is a problem as well.

I am wondering is it possible to see both objects and if yes can someone guide me or help me out, please.

Thank you

Comment: You should go through the [Unity Multiplayer Manual](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking?_ga=2.259765385.223569617.1538389525-2141040499.1490886544). What you describe can easily be done using the [NetworkTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransform.html) so a Player uses Vuforia for his own stuff and gets the objects from the other player over network. Please do your research and come back with a specific programming issue

Comment: @AniruddhParihar 1) you don't need to comment that you made an edit and 2) "I've stetted up" is not grammatically correct (or [even the right word](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stetted)).